# Keep first 30 characters for files names

Tags: batch-file

I have this code which should keep the first 30 characters for each filename in a directory...For some reason this code does not truncate the names. can you please help me understand why?

```
cd C:\Users\AGL\Documents\test

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.csv') do (
    set "name=%%~na"
    set "ext=%%~xa"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "nname=!name:~0,-30!"
     endlocal
)

pause
```

Comment: You haven't asked the code to do anything other than define some variables. Can you please explain where the issue lies in your posted code?

Comment: this line does not do the renaming ? set "nname=!name:~0,-30!"

Comment: it only sets the new variable `nname` to the last 30 characters of `!name!`

Comment: Do you actually want to rename all the `csv` files?

Comment: I see - can you please help me modify this code to remove last 30 characters from each filename?

Comment: yes I need to rename all csv files in a folder

Comment: I can, but please show me an example of a name and how you want it to be.

Comment: Perhaps, changing the `set` command to the `ren` command would be a solution, i.e. `ren "%%a" "!name:~,-30!%%~xa"`!

Comment: sure - here is the filename AUDCAD_1 Min_Ask_2019.10.01_2019.10.17.csv   Actually I need to keep only 17 first characters AUDCAD_1 Min_Ask.csv

Comment: ok.. I count 16 characters, but anyway, see answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you tried to do this?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "C:\Users\AGL\Documents\test"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.csv') do (
    set "name=%%~na"
    ren "%%~a" "!name:~0,16!%%~xa"
)
pause
```